# How to save image on Linux (Debian) using ASP.NET CORE 3

Tags: c#, linux, debian, asp.net-core-3.0, blobstorage

I will have to accomplish this new task, to save images on Linux (Debian) server using ASP.NET Core 3. Any idea how to do that. What are the best practices? Any advice are welcome.

thnx

Comment: You can use Docker to create and save Debian image, and to interact with it with .net you can use https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet

Comment: I'm not clear, do you want to save the docker image in Linux (Debian) server via the APS.NET Core 3 code? not the docker command?

Comment: Do I miss something or how does docker come up in the question?

Comment: No docker. I want to save images on Debian file system. I need a BLOB.

Comment: @Wasyster, where are you hosting your asp.net core web site? in azure or localhost or on that Linux server?

Comment: @Ivan Yang on Linux server, runing Debian 9

Answer (score 0):

If the blob you mentioned is azure blob storage, you can take a look the following solutions as per your need.

**1**.If you want to use asp.net core save images to azure blob storage -> then from blob storage, save it to linux file system.

You can first install this nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) to your asp.net core, and refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) for saving images to azure blob storage via code(**Note that** this code is for this older package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), you need to modify a little). When the images are stored in azure blob storage, you can use [blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux#overview) to map blob storage to your linux server.

**2**.If you just want to directly save images from asp.net core to linux server, then you should setup a ftp server in the linux server, then directly save images to that linux via ftp.

Hope it helps.